# Authentication Dialogue Box Disappears Instantly

Tags: password, authentication

Note: I'm using KDE

So, as of a few days ago, any time I'd have to enter my password (eg updating through Discover) the dialogue box pops up then disappears immediately before I can enter anything.
This is immediately followed by a notification that I don't have permission.

Has anyone experienced this?

What do I do?